# What is the 'play' host?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, hostname, localhost

I tested the following on a Ubuntu machine.

The command

```
ping play
```

results in

```
PING play (127.0.53.53) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.032 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
```

If I do the following:

```
ssh play
```

I can log in to my own machine `localhost`.

Finally, the following:

```
dig play
```

Results in:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> play
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 55239
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 5, ADDITIONAL: 10

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;play.              IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
play.           847 IN  A   127.0.53.53

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
play.           170047  IN  NS  ns-tld2.charlestonroadregistry.com.
play.           170047  IN  NS  ns-tld1.charlestonroadregistry.com.
play.           170047  IN  NS  ns-tld4.charlestonroadregistry.com.
play.           170047  IN  NS  ns-tld5.charlestonroadregistry.com.
play.           170047  IN  NS  ns-tld3.charlestonroadregistry.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns-tld1.charlestonroadregistry.com. 26751 IN A  216.239.XX.XXX
ns-tld1.charlestonroadregistry.com. 26751 IN AAAA 2001:4860:4802:32::69
ns-tld2.charlestonroadregistry.com. 26751 IN A  216.239.XX.XXX
ns-tld2.charlestonroadregistry.com. 26751 IN AAAA 2001:4860:4802:34::69
ns-tld3.charlestonroadregistry.com. 26751 IN A  216.239.XX.XXX
ns-tld3.charlestonroadregistry.com. 26751 IN AAAA 2001:4860:4802:36::69
ns-tld4.charlestonroadregistry.com. 26751 IN A  216.239.XX.XXX
ns-tld4.charlestonroadregistry.com. 26751 IN AAAA 2001:4860:4802:38::69
ns-tld5.charlestonroadregistry.com. 26751 IN A  216.239.XX.XXX
ns-tld5.charlestonroadregistry.com. 26751 IN AAAA 2001:4860:4805::69

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 192.XXX.XXX.XXX#53(192.XXX.XXX.XXX)
;; WHEN: Mon Mar 14 16:07:58 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 394
```

(I replaced the octets in IP addresses by XXX's)

What is this strange 'play' host?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like NCOMF - have a read of [THIS](https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2-2014-08-01-en)

Comment: I tested it on four machines in four different networks. It's always the same. Where could this collision or misconfiguration come from?